# Badge shown in "Achievements" depends on the site I'm currently on

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

I received a Tumbleweed badge yesterday. This morning, I noticed some odd behavior in the "Achievements" menu. Despite the badge being awarded on "Android Enthusiasts", when viewing it from Biology:

[image: Badge on Biology Site]

It shows it as a Biology badge, and when viewing it from Chemistry:

[image: Badge on Chemistry Site]

It shows it as a Chemistry badge.

Is this intended behavior? This seems odd to me. Since the badge was awarded on Android, I'd expect it to show an Android badge (The top-half of an android-bot head).